# Nginx Url Rewrite

Tags: nginx

Aim: To rewrite url's into a application compatible format

Progress: I have a rewrite from domain root that is working fine, however when I add /foo/ or /bar/ I just get a 404 as it tries to match that location within my config.

eg..

http://domain.com/    # Working fine

http://domain.com/foo/  # getting 404 - i assume it is failing to match location

I have the application url which I have added $request_uri to the end, however I want to be able to pass the /foo/ or /bar/ into the url to have it work correctly.

I have tried $request_body $request_uri$1 and varies combinations, however no luck just a 404.

How would I go about doing this? Which $variable do I need to pass into url?

An example of the url below. Not the exact one, but hopefully enough to get an idea.

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/$ pt/Wondering?virtual-webr00t=http://foobar.com&pagename=123/Dispatcher&url-path=$request_uri` last;
}

location /pt/Wondering {

        proxy_pass http://domain.com;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        root    html;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the below

```
rewrite ^/$   # Starts with / and ends with /
```

When you should be using

```
rewrite ^/ # start with / and accepts anything afterwards
```

The difference is the regex.